# Requirements coverage without tracebabilty matrix

Tags: testing, requirements, traceability

How to check whether the test case has covered all the requirements other than tracebaility matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tool for this, if this is what you are looking for. Having said that 100% test coverage of requirements in unattainable. Your coverage should always be driven by specific situation, including the desires of the stakeholders. I recommend you read about [context driven testing](http://www.context-driven-testing.com/).

You can use a mix of traceability matrix and code coverage to get a reasonable idea if you want.